# git lfs loosing references on an external hard drive

Tags: git, git-lfs

I'm using an external hard drive to store my git repository. We are using git lfs to manage our larger files. My problem is that whenever I move the hard drive to another machine, git lists all the large files as modified or sometimes deleted. It seems that LFS does not store the references to this metadata on the external drive.

I'm looking for a solution for this problem but so far the only way I have of cleaning this up is if I make sure I checkout from master before I start working on a machine different from the last time I pushed to the repository. My next guess at a solution is finding LFSs configuration so that I can store the metadata on the drive rather than on the individual machines. Any suggestions for how to do that or perhaps a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Normally the large files should be stored under the `.git` directory; so if the repo is on the external drive, the large objects should be, too.

```
./
    .git/
        lfs/
            objects/
                /* this is where the large files live */
        objects/
            /* this is where the database for the core repo lives */
```

Moreover, if the LFS data were missing, git would not report that as a file being modified or deleted.

Is it possibly a disagreement between machines about whether filenames are case sensitive for the repo in question?  That seems to best fit the symptoms.